# SQL sum elapsed duration between rows for values outside limit bound for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

Bit of a SQL amateur, so stuck with translating what would be easy C++/Python/Excel function to SQL query using SQL CLR post-processing add-in from VantagePoint.  Looking to do something like this excel functionality, so I'd have just the timestamp and value. Looking to do a computation for total elapsed time between readings if the value at a reading is less than a lower bound then add to that running sum, and same for a running sum for readings above a lower bound.

https://image.ibb.co/dJr0kR/SQLTime_Diff.png

This would be normal pseudocode, but unsure how it would translate into SQL with CLR

```
foreach(row)
    if(value < lowLimit)
        lowSum += (time[row] - time[row - 1])
    if(value > highLimit)
        highSum +=(time[row] - time[row - 1])
```

And then I could add to the report I'm building the final value for each sum. Purpose is to visualize/alert if the elapsed time outside limit is greater than a given acceptable range

Comment: What version of SQL? Can you show us the structure of the tables involved? Sample data would also be helpful.

Comment: Which dbms????  SQL is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Each of them has their own syntax.

Comment: MMSQL 2012. Eventually will be using PH values, but for now using the sample data provided with vantage point

This is the historized data I can pull

http://image.ibb.co/c5NyN6/so1.png

So I eventually just need x seconds under limit y seconds over limit

This is provided Rockwell Vantage Point stored proc


http://image.ibb.co/e6Nhh6/so2.png

Comment: and what the sum_in_state excel

http://image.ibb.co/fyJNh6/so5.png

Comment: Problems still are I cannot replicate the #timeseries in sql. I've tried pruning it down to this, but then can't get rowID from the historized table I can produce

http://image.ibb.co/cREpUm/so6.png

and here's the full available data I can pull from historized data, all I would need is timestamp and valueasfloat, will have similar data when I get actual data

http://image.ibb.co/fXChh6/so7.png

Answer (score 2):

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (RowDate DATETIME, val INT)
```

You could use the `LAG()` function to get the previous timestamp value. Then put that into a `SUM()` that only adds the delta if the `val` value is less than the lowLimit of 5 or greater than the highLimit of 6.

```
SELECT 
    lowSum = SUM(CASE WHEN val < 5 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,RowDate,LAG(RowDate) OVER (ORDER BY RowDate ASC)) END)
    ,highSum = SUM(CASE WHEN val > 6 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,RowDate,LAG(RowDate) OVER (ORDER BY RowDate ASC)) END)
FROM TableA
```